# Definite Integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\,dx$

Needed a detailed solution with explanation. The answer is $2$.

Comment: If this is homework, *please say so*. It would help you if you show your working so far too :)

Comment: @Shaun- I had come till putting values tanx=u^2.

Comment: @shaun- i am currently not familiar with Mathjax input. So I will be giving proper solution after completing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x\cos x}=\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x}}\frac1{\cos^2x}=\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\tan x}\sec^2x$$

Put $\sqrt{\tan x}=u\implies \tan x=u^2 $

Comment: getting 2du after that?

Comment: @Swetank, getting $$\int_0^1\frac{u}{u^2}2u du$$

Comment: yes but, upper limit is pi/4...

Comment: @Swetank, that upper limit is for $x\implies u=+\sqrt{\tan x}=??$

Comment: Ohh yeah! that upper limit is for x. therefore sqrt tanx will be 1.

Comment: How do we define the value of upper limit of u?

Comment: @Swetank, If $x=\frac\pi4, u=+\sqrt{\tan \frac\pi4}=+1$

Comment: yeah got it! so after putting upper-lower limits i am getting 2du. Will 'du' will be removed due to integration? and hence the answer will be 2. Is that okay?

Comment: @Swetank, what if $\int dx?$

Comment: Integral of dx will be x + c.

Comment: @Swetank, so, $2\int_0^1du=2[u+c]_1^0$

Comment: Very very much Thanks!! In your previous comment the upper limit is 0 and lower limit is 1, it should be opposite, upper limit 1 and lower limit 0. Isn't it? A

Comment: One more additional question as i am revising up, why did in the first line did we multiplied and divided num. and deno. by cos^2 x?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the result that has been pointed out by Bhattacharjee.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x\cos x}dx&=\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\tan x}\sec^2x\;dx\\
&=\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{-\frac{1}{2}} x\;d(\tan x)\\
&=2\left.\sqrt{\tan x}\right|_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\\
&=2.
\end{align}
$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: Changing $dx$ to $d(\tan x)$ is, in fact the act of substituting.